# Глагол "обжигать"

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

**Вопрос № 290567 (с Грамоты.ру)**
Еще раз здравствуйте, Уважаемая Грамота! Разрешите задать ещё один вопрос. В данном предложении глагол ОБЖИГАВШЕМ стоит в правильной форме, если предложение повествуется в прошедшем времени??? Я вытащила обратно листок, сжала в кулаке и обратилась к девушке, желая побыстрее избавиться от кусочка бумаги, неожиданно ОБЖИГАВШЕМ ладонь.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

В зависимости от смысла возможны два варианта: избавиться от кусочка бумаги, неожиданно обжегшего ладонь и избавиться от кусочка бумаги, неожиданно **обжигавшего** ладонь.

```
    Мой вопрос
```

Какая смысловая разница между этими двумя примерами? С первым все ясно. А как понять второй пример? Мне кажется, если есть наречие "неожиданно", то о несовершенном виде глагола речи не может быть в этом конкретном случае.

Comment: Согласен, по-моему, бессмыслица с несовершенным видом, с "неожиданно" только "обжегший" может быть, действительно.

Comment: Возможен фантастический случай, когда этот лист на ладони периодически саморазогревался и всякий раз - неожиданно, когда о предыдущей неприятности успевали забыть, увлекшись основным занятием :)

Comment: Да, Александр, я тоже так думаю. А просить их прокомментировать свой ответ - бессмысленно.

Comment: Обжигать нельзя обжечь.

Comment: Всё-таки как плохо Ё не писать! Написал "обжёгший" через Е, забыв, как правильно произносится (а я всегда Ё пишу, с какого-то момента в жизни). Совершенно уверен, что многие произносят Е на месте Ё в некоторых словах, п. ч. видят их написанными через Е и не догадываются, как правильно.

Comment: А идея Александра хорошая!) Может, вообще бы не додумался даже до такой не очень правдоподобной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я вытащила обратно листок, сжала в кулаке и обратилась к девушке, желая побыстрее избавиться от кусочка бумаги,  обжигавшего ладонь.**

Нельзя сказать: кусочек бумаги неожиданно обжигал ладонь. И не очень корректно говорить: кусочек бумаги неожиданно обжёг ладонь (и продолжал обжигать?).

Поэтому надо решительно избавиться от этого "неожиданно", лучше сказать так: Мне **вдруг стало казаться**, что кусочек бумаги  обжигает ладонь. Но в причастный оборот может поместиться только часть информации: "...избавиться от кусочка бумаги,  обжигавшего ладонь".

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я тоже об этом думал. Просто хотел узнать, насколько корректен тот вариант, который советует Грамота.

Answer (score 3):

Возможен вариант, что кусочек бумаги «обжигал» ладонь продолжительное время, но само это свойство — обжигать ладонь — было для него несвойственным и потому неожиданным.

Примерно как «Андрей оказался неожиданно рослым для своих лет».

Или примерно как если бы вместо «неожиданно обжигавшего ладонь» было бы просто «неожиданно горячего».

Comment: Теоретически такой вариант возможен, но вот на практике...